# How can i uninstall this desktop package that has installed itself? blue screen with no terminal, ubuntu server 20.10

Tags: command-line, server, package-management, desktop-environments, 20.10

So ive installed alot of packages, and one of them has installed a desktop environment over my ubuntu server install. I dont mind this really but i wanted to keep ubuntu server as it was, in the command line for max performance capacity.

It gives me the desktop login page, after login i am presented with this:

[image]

I use alt + f2 to open command but unable to launch a terminal, with error: 'command not found'. If i logout, i cant use ctrl + alt + f2 from login screen to open a terminal that way... I have to reboot and before i login at all im able to access the usual terminal through ctrl + alt + f2, however not once i login...

How do i launch a terminal from desktop?

How does this desktop environment affect performance? if im at login screen with alt + f1, how does it affect my performance in alt + f2?

Which package installed this?

How can i unsinstall this?

Please advise...

Comment: Launch standard terminal is Ctrl+Alt+T. Does that work? If you click on the down arrow ▼ top right of the system tray and select Settings, About it should tell you what you have installed as your desktop environment.

Comment: This can be a very easy and fast question to answer if you provide the complete list of what was installed. If you don't know what you installed, review your /var/log/apt/history.log. Copy the lists right out of the log into your question. Don't make us guess. Guessing is an awful game: Slow, error-prone, and no fun at all.

Comment: thanks for your replies, I have no idea what was installed, this is why i asked the question "which package installed this?", i will now go away and review the logs... as for CTRL + ALT + T, i will get back to you 24601.